# Rails: circular Many to Many relation between 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Lets say, I've three models.

- **User** (can post many Questions)
- **Question** (can have many Answers)
- **Answer** (user can post many Answers)

Now I can create association like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Now if I do that then for finding answers of any user for a particular question query will be:

```
@answers = User.find(params[:id]).answers.where(:question_id => params[:question_id])
```

Is there any better solution? Should I have to modify the association or it is the way?

Comment: Depends, do the users always write in their own answers or should there preset options? Do you need a user interface for users to create questions?

Comment: @max, Yes users got a interface for creating/updating their question. Also, they can answer their own question.

Comment: Your solution looks optimal to me. Do you have any concerns about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need users to be able to create surveys with questions and preset answers from a crud interface than those relations are just not going to cut it. Its also not very optimal if you want to generate metrics - like say the most common answers.

Instead consider using separate tables for the answer "presets" and the replies submitted by those answering the question.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :replies
  has_many :selected_answers, through: :replies,
                              source: :answer
  has_many :answered_questions, through: :replies,
                                source: :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
  has_many :replies, through: :answers
end

# this is a "preset"
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :replies 
end

# this is the answer checked by a user
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
  has_one :question, through: :answer
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you have user foreign key on answers you can simply do:

```
@answers = Answer.where(user_id: params[:id], question_id: params[:question_id])
```

Comment: yes this is a way. But is this the best solution for the scenario? (+1)

Comment: "Best solution" is subjective and hard to prove, but it's tough to conceive of anything simpler than this for the model relationships specified -- it's just a single-table query on two parameters, both of which are needed for the result. The example in your question will work, but is more complicated and involves an unnecessary join.